# WooCommerce - Get selected variation for a product in cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Hello,

Any one please help me find the solution.

My client has a wholesale business, in which he don't need woocommerce checkout functionality. He needs woocommerce functionality upto cart, but instead of checkout he wants a "Place Order" button.

Now, everything is working fine, placing order correctly, order is storing into database and mailing to admin, but the problem is that I want to store variations as well, my question is ***how to get selected variation*** *(if there is any)* ***of a product inside functions.php for that product, which is already in cart?***

Any hint will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 13):

Hope that I've understood your query correctly.

You are saying that you want to get variations detail (if available) of the product, which is there in cart.

Cart contains many items. You can loop over items & can get variation details of each items.

A cart item is an associative array & you may find product id in `$item['product_id']` & variation id in `$item['variation_id']`

Please use following function & pass variation id to get variation detail:

```
function get_variation_data_from_variation_id( $item_id ) {
    $_product = new WC_Product_Variation( $item_id );
    $variation_data = $_product->get_variation_attributes();
    $variation_detail = woocommerce_get_formatted_variation( $variation_data, true );  // this will give all variation detail in one line
    // $variation_detail = woocommerce_get_formatted_variation( $variation_data, false);  // this will give all variation detail one by one
    return $variation_detail; // $variation_detail will return string containing variation detail which can be used to print on website
    // return $variation_data; // $variation_data will return only the data which can be used to store variation data
}
```

Now let's see how to use this function

```
$item_id = ( !empty( $cart_item['variation_id'] ) ) ? $cart_item['variation_id'] : '';
if ( !empty( $item_id ) ) {
   $variations = get_variation_data_from_variation_id( $item_id );
}
```

Hope it'll be useful.

Comment: Thank you @Ratnakar, your comment "A cart item is an associative array" helped me.

Comment: Thank you @Ratnakar, you made my day :)

Answer (score 1):

Hope this one will help...

```
function woocommerce_variable_add_to_carts() {
        global $product, $post;
        $variations = $product->get_available_variations();
        foreach ($variations as $key => $value) {
            ?>
            <form action="<?php echo esc_url($product->add_to_cart_url()); ?>"method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
                <input type="hidden" name="variation_id" value="<?php echo $value['variation_id'] ?>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<?php echo esc_attr($post->ID); ?>" />
                <?php
                if (!empty($value['attributes'])) {
                    foreach ($value['attributes'] as $attr_key => $attr_value) {
                        ?>
                        <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $attr_key ?>" value="<?php echo $attr_value ?>">
                        <?php
                    }
                }
                ?>

                <?php echo implode('/', $value['attributes']); ?>

                <?php echo $value['price_html']; ?>
                </
                <button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt"><?php echo apply_filters('single_add_to_cart_text', __('Add to cart', 'woocommerce'), $product->product_type); ?></button>

            </form>
            <?php
        }
    }
```